# Can I wake the Windows 10 screensaver using the shift key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, screensaver, wake-up, shift

Admittedly, this is a pretty trivial problem...

I'm in the habit of using the shift key to wake up a sleeping computer (either in suspend or just in screensaving mode). I do this because it is a key that rarely has any effect on its own and it has worked on every computer I have ever owned. Even the screen blanking in the linux console can be woken with a tap of the shift key.

I just upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 on my game machine and the fact that the shift key no longer works to wake the screen (from the screen saver) is bugging me. Does anyone know if it is possible to re-enable this "feature"?

To clarify, I'm not asking about waking a machine from suspend mode (which is more of a hardware thing than an operating system thing) but the fact that when the Windows 10 screensaver is visible, hitting shift has no effect. I need to hit enter or space or some other key.

Comment: I thought any key press would wake a windows pc....strange. Fired up my W10 laptop, shift key wakes it up....

Comment: Screensaver is not sleep, your Title and question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Shift works for me as well. Maybe try moving the keyboard to another USB port.

Comment: To add some anecdotal evidence, shift doesn't work for me either. It's absolutely a software thing. I've had this PC for a decade and shift worked fine in Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Linux. Only Windows 10 does this. Minor but somehow still infuriating.